# Are there any good Ranged Cleric options in 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric, ranged-attack

Clerics aren't a ranged class by default, but sometimes you need that adaptability, especially if you are pinned down or can't move. I have found some minor ranged Cleric at-wills (Lance of Faith mostly) but they are short on range. Are there any good powers, feats, etc, I could take to give him a basic ranged attack? If not, are there any other good at-will powers that will at least let him target something other than AC?

Currently his stats are based around Strength and Wisdom with constitution as his third highest and Charisma as a dump.

Comment: Are you playing the AEDU version of the cleric (Templar) or the Essentials version (Warpriest)?

Comment: I started with the PHB version of the Cleric and started adding powers from all over. As far as I am aware, Warpriest powers would be 0k to take in this game.

Comment: Right I just wanted to know what your base class was, the PHB cleric easily has a ranged build, Warpriest, not so much.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes its called a Laser Cleric**

Laser Cleric is a build for the 4e Cleric(Templar) class focused on making ranged, radiant attacks and handing out buffs to allies and debuffs to enemies. You choose holy symbol implement powers and can pretty much avoid making any melee attacks at all. Wisdom is your primary stat, charisma gets a boost for some rider effects. Dex probably becomes your dump stat since you need INT for most of your skills.

I would highly recommend you check out the [Cleric's Handbook](http://community.wizards.com/forum/4e-character-optimization/threads/2259786) over on the [WOTC optimization forums](http://community.wizards.com/forum/4e-character-optimization/threads/1478896). It can explain in far more depth than I can which powers to take, which feats to take, and which items to take and more importantly *why*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In 4E there are a handful of classes, which include the cleric, for which there are basically two half sets of powers based on two different stats. For the cleric that would be either strength or wisdom. The cleric's strength powers are mostly melee, while the cleric's wisdom powers are nearly exclusively ranged.

So to build a good ranged cleric, ignore strength and all powers that depend on strength. Take exclusively the other half of powers, those based on wisdom. That will give you a ranged healer, buffer, damage dealer.